# Finding maximum of $x+y$

Tags: optimization, lagrange-multiplier, constraints, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, holder-inequality

Let x and y be real numbers satisfying $9x^{2} + 16y^{2} = 1$. Then $x + y$ is maximum when

a. $y = \frac{9x}{16}$

b. $y = −\frac{9x}{16}$

c. $y = \frac{4x}{3}$

d. $y = −\frac{4x}{3}$

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

WLOG $3x=\cos t,4y=\sin t$

$$x+y=\dfrac{\cos t}3+\dfrac{\sin t}4=\dfrac{4\sin t +3\cos t}{12}$$

Now $(4\sin t +3\cos t)^2+(3\sin t -4\cos t)^2=3^2+4^2$

$\implies (4\sin t +3\cos t)^2\le25\iff-5\le4\sin t +3\cos t\le5$

Comment: Right, right, that's almost what I did as well. But this still doesn't give me a relation between $x$ and $y$.

Comment: @junkquill12, We need $3\sin t-4\cos t=0\iff\dfrac{\sin t}4=\dfrac{\cos t}3$ right

Comment: @labbhattacharjee If I may ask, what subject did you study to become so good at algebraic manipulations like here (not asking about this answer specifically, but in general you seem very good at algebraic manipulations, substitutions, inequalities, etc.)? When I open a Real Analysis book, Discrete Math book, etc. there is nothing which teaches me much algebraic skill.

Comment: @Ovi, See https://archive.org/details/higheralgebraseq00hall and  https://archive.org/details/higheralgebra032813mbp

Comment: @labbhattacharjee Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

Let $x+y=c\iff x=c-y$

$$1=9x^2+16y^2=9(c-y)^2+16y^2\iff25y^2-18cy+9c^2-1=0$$

As $y$ is real, the discriminant must be $\ge0$

$$\implies(18c)^2\ge4\cdot25(9c^2-1)\iff144c^2\le25\iff-5\le12c\le5$$

For maximum $c=x+y=\dfrac5{12}$

consequently, $y=\dfrac{18c}{2\cdot25}=\dfrac{9c}{25}\iff x=?$

Comment: I see. But with the discriminant all I will find is a bound on $x+y$, whereas I need to find the ration of $x$ and $y$ which maximises $x+y$. I think if I just differentiate the resultant equation and equate it to $0$ to maximise $y$, I'm on my way to the answer; which I get as option a. Thanks though!

Comment: @junkquill12, Please find the updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

We can solve for $y$
$$
y = \pm \frac{\sqrt{1 - 9 x^2}}{4}
$$
on the ellipse:
$$
\left(\frac{x}{1/3}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{y}{1/4}\right)^2 = 1
$$
Then
$$
f(x) = x + y(x) \le f_+(x) = x + \frac{\sqrt{1 - 9 x^2}}{4}
$$
and for an extremum:
$$
f_+'(x) = 1 + \frac{1}{8 \sqrt{1-9x^2}}(-18 x) = 0 \iff \\
1 = \frac{9x}{4 \sqrt{1-9x^2}} \iff \\
4 \sqrt{1-9x^2} = 9 x \iff \\
16 (1 - 9x^2) = 81 x^2 \iff \\
16 = 225 x^2 \iff \\
x^2 = \frac{16}{225} \iff \\
x = \pm \frac{4}{15}
$$
and thus picking the positive solution for $x$:
$$
y = \frac{\sqrt{1 - 9\cdot 16/225}}{4} = \frac{9}{4\cdot 15} = \frac{3}{20} \Rightarrow \\
\frac{y}{x} = \frac{3}{20} / \frac{4}{15} = \frac{45}{80} = \frac{9}{16}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Because of the signs, the right answer is one of a. or c.

With $y=mx$, we have $$x+y=\frac{1+m}{\sqrt{9+16m^2}}.$$

a.  gives $5/12\approx0.417$;

c. gives $3/\sqrt{337}\approx 0.381$.

Comment: @ Yves Daoust, could you please help me with this question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2166927/if-sin-a-sin2-a-1-and-a-cos12-ab-cos8-ac-cos6-a-1-0

Comment: @LeonhardEuler: sorry, I don't work on demand.

Answer (score 1):

By C-S $$\frac{25}{144}=\frac{1}{9}+\frac{1}{16}=\left(\frac{1}{9}+\frac{1}{16}\right)(9x^2+16y^2)\geq(x+y)^2,$$
which gives $x+y\leq\frac{5}{12}$.

The equality occurs, when $\left(\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{4}\right)||(3x,4y)$, id est, for a.

Answer (score 0):

The shortest solution is using lagrange multipliers. We must maximise $f(x,y) = x+y$ subject to the constraint $g(x,y) = 9x^2 +16y^2 -1$. Now, for extremum, we know that:

$\nabla f = -\lambda .\nabla g$.

substituting, :

$(1,1) = -\lambda.(18x,32y)$ [here, $(a,b)$ denotes the vector $a \hat i + b\hat j$]

Thus clearly, $-\lambda.18x = -\lambda.32y = 1$

Since $\lambda$ cannot be zero here, $y = \frac{9x}{16}$

In case you want to read up on lagrange multipliers, here is the wikipedia article on it: [LAGRANGE MULTIPLIERS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier)

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to use Lagrange multipliers

Maximise $f=x+y $ subject to $9x^2+16y^2=1$

Set up the Lagrangian and set gradient equal zero

\begin{equation}
L = x+y - \lambda (9x^2+16y^2-1)
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\nabla L = 0
\end{equation}
From the partial derivatives
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial L}{\partial x} = 1-18\lambda x=0
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial L}{\partial y} = 1-32\lambda y=0
\end{equation}
So $\lambda = 1/(18x)$ and $y=1/(32\lambda)$

Substituting for $\lambda$ in the equation for $y$ we get

\begin{equation}
y=\frac{9x}{16}
\end{equation}

Answer (score 0):

with Holder,s Inequality

$$(9x^2+16y^2)\cdot \left[\frac{1}{3^2}+\frac{1}{4^2}\right]\geq \bigg[\bigg(16y^2 \cdot \frac{1}{9}\bigg)^{\frac{1}{2}}+\bigg(9x^2 \cdot \frac{1}{16}\bigg)^{\frac{1}{2}}\bigg]^{2}$$

so $$(x+y)^2 \leq \frac{25}{144}\Leftrightarrow (x+y)\leq \frac{5}{12}$$

and equality hold when $$\frac{9x^2}{\frac{1}{3^2}} = \frac{16y^2}{\frac{1}{4^2}}\Leftrightarrow (9x^2)^2 = (16y^2)^2$$