# If $\sin A+\sin^2 A=1$ and $a\cos^{12} A+b\cos^{8} A+c\cos^{6} A-1=0$

Tags: trigonometry

If $\sin A+\sin^2 A=1$ and $a\cos^{12} A+b\cos^{8} A+c\cos^{6} A-1=0$.

Find the value of $2b + \dfrac {c}{a}$.

My Attempt:
$$\sin A+\sin^2 A=1$$
$$\sin A + 1 - \cos^2 A=1$$
$$\sin A=\cos^2 A$$

Now,

$$a(\cos^2 A)^{6}+b(\cos^2 A)^{4}+c(\cos^2 A)^{3}=1$$
$$a\sin^6 A+ b\sin^4 A+c\sin^3 A=1$$

How do I proceed further?

Comment: sobstitute $\sin^2 A = 1-\sin A$

Comment: $\sin A=\cos^2A$

Answer (score 2):

**I write it step by step:**

With $\sin A+\sin^2 A=1$ we have 
$\sin A=1-\sin^2 A=\cos^2A$
so
\begin{eqnarray}
&& a\cos^{12} A+b\cos^{8} A+c\cos^{6} A-1=0\\
&& a(\cos^2A)^6+b(\cos^2A)^4+c(\cos^2A)^3-1=0\\
&& a\sin^6A+b\sin^4A+c\sin^3A-1=0\\
&& a(1-\cos^2A)^3+b(1-\cos^2A)^2+c\sin A(1-\cos^2A)-1=0\\
&& a(1-\sin A)^3+b(1-\sin A)^2+c\sin A(1-\sin A)-1=0\\
&& a(1-3\sin A+3\sin^2A-\sin^3A+b(1-2\sin A+\sin^2A)+c(\sin A-\sin^2 A)-1=0\\
&& a-3a\sin A+3a\sin^2A-a\sin^3A+b-2b\sin A+b\sin^2A+c\sin A-c\sin^2 A-1=0\\
&& a-3a\sin A+3a\sin^2A-a\sin^3A+b-2b\sin A+b\sin^2A+c\sin A-c\sin^2 A-1=0\\
&& a-3a\sin A+3a(1-\cos^2A)-a\sin A(1-\cos^2A)+b-2b\sin A+b(1-\cos^2A)+c\sin A-c(1-\cos^2A)-1=0\\
&& a-3a\sin A+3a(1-\sin A)-a\sin A(1-\sin A)+b-2b\sin A+b(1-\sin A)+c\sin A-c(1-\sin A)-1=0\\
&& a-3a\sin A+3a-3a\sin A-a\sin A+a\sin^2A+b-2b\sin A+b-b\sin A+c\sin A-c+c\sin A-1=0\\
&& a-3a\sin A+3a-3a\sin A-a\sin A+a-a\sin A+b-2b\sin A+b-b\sin A+c\sin A-c+c\sin A-1=0\\
&& (a+3a+a+b+b-c-1)+(-3a-3a-a-a-2b-b+c+c)\sin A=0\\
&& (5a+2b-c-1)+(-8a-3b+2c)\sin A=0
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: @ My Glasses, what is $2b+\dfrac {c}{a}$?

Comment: @LeonhardEuler This last equation has infinite solutions, but if we restrict it with some conditions, like $a$, $b$ and $c$ be integer, so we can answer that!. Meanwhile, I tried find this expression $2b+\dfrac{c}{a}$ independent from equation, but it is very complicated in general form.

Comment: @ My Glasses, then what would be the answer?. Could you please elaborate?

Answer (score 1):

$$\sin A= \cos ^2A→\sin^2A=\cos^4A→1-\cos^2A=\cos^4A\\
(\cos^2A)^2+(\cos^2A)-1=0→\cos^2A=\frac{-1+ \sqrt{5}}{2}$$

So,

$$a\left(\frac{-1+ \sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^6+b\left(\frac{-1+ \sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^4+c\left(\frac{-1+ \sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^3=1\\
a(9-4\sqrt{5})+b\left(\frac{7-3\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)+c(\sqrt{5}-2)=1\\
(9a+7b/2-2c)+(-4a-3b/2+c)\sqrt{5}=1$$

Maybe the question want:

$$9a+\frac{7b}{2}-2c=1→18a+7b-4c=2\\
-4a-\frac{3b}{2}+c=0→8a+3b=2c$$

But on that case we get:

$$b=2-2a\\
c=a+3$$

And then

$$2b+\frac{c}{a}=5-4a+\frac{3}{a}$$

and the result depends on $a$. Otherwise I don't have another guess.

Comment: @ Arnaldo, How is $$\textrm a(\dfrac {-1+\sqrt {5}}{2})^{6}=a(9-4\sqrt {5})$$, $....$?

Comment: You just have to do the calculation!

Comment: [+1] very good answer if you assume that the looked for coefficients are rationals.

Answer (score 0):

@MyGlasses .. In the third line from below you forgot that there is $(-a)$ twice in your attempt to prove the required identity, resulting in a mistake in your answer.

Comment: $a\sin^{2}A=a(1-\cos^{2}A)=a(1-\sin A)$

Comment: Yes, you  are right, thanks.

Answer (score -1):

HINT:

$$\cos^4A=(\cos^2A)^2=\cdots=1-\cos^2A\iff\cos^4A+\cos^2A-1=0$$

Divide $a\cos^{12}A+b\cos^8A+c\cos^8A-1$ by $\cos^4A+\cos^2A-1$

Comment: @ lab bhattacharjee, could you please elaborate the very beginning step?

Comment: @LeonhardEuler, Was planning to use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_remainder_theorem

Comment: @ lab bhattacharjee, where did you use that? Could you please show?

Comment: @LeonhardEuler, In the division suggested, the remainder has to be $0$

Comment: @ lab bhattacharjee, then how do you get $cos^4 A+cos^2A-1=0$? and is the division to be done by actual division method?

Comment: @LeonhardEuler, $$(\cos^2A)^2=(\sin A)^2=1-\cos^2A$$ right?

Comment: @ lab bhattacharjee, yeah and then...?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54571/discussion-between-lab-bhattacharjee-and-leonhard-euler).