# If $a, b, c$ are reals prove that $ (a^3+b^3) \le (a^2+b^2)•(a^4+b^4) $

Tags: inequality

If a,b,c are reals prove that $$ (a^3+b^3) \le (a^2+b^2)•(a^4+b^4) $$

Now I tried AM GM on the RHS of the inequality and got $ 4a^3•b^3 \le (a^2+b^2)•(a^4+b^4) $ 
So now it suffices to show that $a^3+b^3 \le 4a^3•b^3 $ 
Thats were i am stuck .Thank for the help.

Comment: hint: prove it case by case, first suppose a,b>1 ,etc.

Comment: a=0, b=0.9 is a counter-example, and what is c?

Comment: use `\cdot` instead of •

Comment: $(a^3+b^3)\leq (a^2+b^2)(a^4+b^4)$ ... The left is degree 3, the right is degree 6, there is no possibility this holds for all positive reals.  It s false when $a,b$ are small and true when $a,b$ are large.

Comment: I am looking a t the book and I have copied the question correctly. Most probably it is multiplication sign between the cubes as the question I from the collection on AM GM . Thank you

Answer (score 3):

The statement should have been $$(a^3+b^3)^2\leq (a^2+b^2)(a^4+b^4),$$
which is a result of the Cauchy- Schwarz inequality.

Let $u=\langle a,\,b\rangle$ and $v=\langle a^2,\,b^2\rangle$.

We have $$|u.v|^2\le ||u||^2||v||^2,$$ which implies the inequality.

Answer (score 1):

The inequality is not true in the case when $a=b=0.5$. Indeed, $(0.5^2+0.5^2)(0.5^4+0.5^4)=\frac{1}{16}$ and $0.5^3+0.5^3=\frac{1}{4}$. However, the inequality$$(a^3+b^3)^2\leq (a^2+b^2)(a^4+b^4)$$always holds true for all real numbers $a$ and $b$. This comes using the CS inequality.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $$(a^2+b^2)(a^4+b^4)-(a^3+b^3)^2={a}^{2}{b}^{2} \left( a-b \right) ^{2}\geq 0$$

Comment: You gave the same answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2167155/42969. Do you *ever* check if a question has been asked and answered before, and vote to close as a duplicate if appropriate?

Comment: Sorry, i didn't check this!