# Euler Identities.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

By application of Euler Identities we get that the Fourier Series of $f$ which is given by:
$$f(\theta)\thicksim \sum_{n \ne o}\frac{(-1) ^ {n + 1}}{in} e^{in\theta} $$
is equal to $$2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n+1}\frac{sinn\theta}{n} $$

I have divided the summation $\sum_{n\ne0}$ to $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1) ^ {n + 1}}{in} e^{in\theta} $ and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1) ^ {-n + 1}}{i(-n)} e^{i(-n)\theta} $ and I know that in the second summation $ \frac{(-1) ^ {-n + 1}}{i(-n)}$ will become $ \frac{(-1) ^ {-n + 2}}{i(n)}$, So How can I reach the final formula that he wants?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**
$$f(\theta)\thicksim \sum_{n \ne o}\frac{(-1) ^ {n + 1}}{in} e^{in\theta} =\sum_{n < o}\frac{(-1) ^ {n + 1}}{in} e^{in\theta}+\sum_{n > o}\frac{(-1) ^ {n + 1}}{in} e^{in\theta}=\sum_{n > o}\frac{(-1) ^ {-n + 1}}{-in} e^{-in\theta}+\sum_{n > o}\frac{(-1) ^ {n + 1}}{in} e^{in\theta}=\sum_{n > o}\frac{(-1) ^ {n + 1}}{in} (-e^{-in\theta}+e^{in\theta})$$

Comment: But I have a problem in your last step and how it comes from the step before last even though we have in the first summation in the step before last $$(-1)^{-n +1}$$ the power contains (-n) not n as in the second summation in the step before last.

Comment: $(-1)^{-n+1}=(-1)^{-n+1}(-1)^{2n}=(-1)^{n+1}$

Comment: @MyGlasses,for the link http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2166927/if-sin-a-sin2-a-1-and-a-cos12-ab-cos8-ac-cos6-a-1-0 In the sixth line from below there was a term $a\sin^{2}A $ you substitute for it by the term $a(1−sinA)$ in the fifth line from below in your try for proving the required identity, this made a mistake in your answer.