# Trigonometry- Find the variables

Tags: trigonometry

This question is about trigonometry and sine, I have tried solving some but what do you do afterwards?

If $\sin A+\sin^2A=1$

And $a \cos^{12} A+b\cos^8A+c\cos^6A-1=0$

Then what is 
$$b+\frac{c}{a}+b$$

[image]

I have tried doing the above, but what is the next steps?

Comment: Please re-edit the post, so it becomes understandable.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2166927/if-sin-a-sin2-a-1-and-a-cos12-ab-cos8-ac-cos6-a-1-0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this is *one possible approach*:

We have: $$\sin^2 A + \sin A - 1 = 0 \implies \sin A = \frac{\sqrt5-1}{2}$$ as we ignore the other root because it is $>1$.

Now, we are required to simplify $a\cos^{12} A + b\cos^8 A + c\cos^6 A -1 =0$. You have already correctly simplified $\sin A = \cos^2 A$. Then our equation becomes: $$a\sin^6 A + b\sin ^4 A + c\sin^3 A -1 =0 \tag{1}$$

By calculating the required powers of $\sin A$, $(1)$ becomes: $$a(9-4\sqrt5)+b(\frac72-\frac32\sqrt5)+c(-2+\sqrt5)-1=0$$

On analysis, we can get one possible solution of $(a,b,c)$ as $(9+4\sqrt5, \frac72+\frac32\sqrt5, -2-\sqrt5)$.

I leave the last bit of calculation to you.