# $\sin A + \sin^2 A = 1$

Tags: trigonometry, polynomials

If $\sin A + \sin^2 A = 1$ then find the value of $$\cos^{12} A + 3\cos^{10} A + 3\cos^8 A + \cos^6 A + 2\cos^4 A + \cos^2 A - 2$$

My Attempt:

I get a relation $\sin A = \cos^2 A$ and I used graphical approach but I'm unable to find required value. Please help me

Comment: Perhaps raise the left hand side to the power 6, apply the binimial theorem, then use $\cos^2 x=1-\sin^2 x$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2166927/if-sin-a-sin2-a-1-and-a-cos12-ab-cos8-ac-cos6-a-1-0

Answer (score 1):

Just use the second relation you derived to replace all of the cosine terms with sin terms, and then use the first main relation repetitively to find the value

Hint:
for the last three terms,

$ 2cos^4A + cos^2A - 2 = 2sin^2A + sinA - 2 = sin^2A + (sin^2A + sinA) - 2 = sin^2A - 1$

similiarly,

$3cos^8A + cos^6A = 3sin^4A + sin^3A = sin^3A \cdot(3sin^2A + sinA) = sin^3A \cdot(2sin^2A + 1) = 2sin^5A + sin^3A$

... and so on till entire thing is simplified.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: letting $x = \cos ^4 (A)$ and $y = \cos^2(A)$, your expression simplifies/factors to $$(x+y)^3 + 2x + y -2.$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $\sin A=x$.

Thus, by your work and by using dividing polynomials we obtain: $$\cos^{12} A + 3\cos^{10}A + 3\cos^{8} A + \cos^6 A + 2\cos^4 A + \cos^2 A - 2=$$
$$=\sin^6A+3\sin^5A+3\sin^4A+\sin^3A+2\sin^2A+\sin A-2=$$
$$=x^6+3x^5+3x^4+x^3+2x^2+x-2=$$
$$=(x^4+2x^3+2x^2+x+3)(x^2+x-1)+1-x=1-x.$$ 
Can you end it now?

Answer (score 0):

It is an algebraic calculation.

Let $x = Sin(A)$

Let us successively calculate the powers of $Cos^2(A)$

By hypothesis $x+x^2=1$. We use this relation to lower the powers of x:

$Cos^2 A=1-Sin^2 A=1-x^2=x$

$Cos^4 A = (Cos^2 A)^2=x^2=1-x$

$Cos^6 A = (Cos^4 A)(Cos^2 A)=(1-x)x=x-x^2=2x-1$

$Cos^8 A = (Cos^6 A)(Cos^2 A)=(2x-1)x=2x^2-x=2-3x$

$Cos^{10} A=(Cos^8 A) (Cos^2 A)=(2-3x)x=5x-3$

$Cos^{12} A=(Cos^{10} A)( Cos^2 A)=(5x-3)x=5(1-x)-3x=5-8x$

It remains to replace:

$5-8x+3(5x-3)+3(2-3x)+2x-1+2(1-x)+x-2=1-x$